# Why mongodb query data from removed shards

Tags: mongodb, sharding, transfer

My application query data from removed shards

old cluster:

1. data shards: set_0(on machine0), set_1(on machine1), set_2(on
   machine2)
2. configserver(on machine2)
3. mongos(on machine2)

new cluster:

1. data shards: shard_0(on new machine0), shard_1(on new machine1)
2. configserver(on new machine0 and new machine1, they're replset)
3. mongos(on new machine0, new machine1)

   Previously, I had three data shards in my mongodb cluster. And I wanted to move the whole cluster to new machines. I did that through adding new data shards into cluster, and remove old data shards from cluster one at a time.

   And I moved configserver through adding new configserver to the old configserver replset and changed the primary to secondary and the secondary to primary.

   Then I initiate mongos in my new cluster

   The whole process went very smoothly. But when my application query some data from new cluster, it sometimes query them from removed shard(set_2), set_2 is a primary shard of my database, but I don't have any unsharded collections in my database any way.(so I don't need use movePrimary method, the removeShard on set2 finished with no fault)